# reference request - moments zeta function/dirichlet polynomials

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

I would like to study some material on the moments of the Riemann Zeta function and  Dirichlet polynomials (mean value theorems). I was looking both for some introductory material and for some more advanced one. If possible I would like material with as much details as possible.

Do you know anything that could be helpful? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://gen.lib.rus.ec/search.php?req=titchmarsh+zeta

Comment: do you know any other reference, lecture notes?

Comment: I actually haven't read Titchmarsh but I was told that it is pretty advanced (research level) so I was looking also for some references more user friendly where all the details are worked out. Probabily I should first give a try to Titchmarsh.

Comment: Then see Apostol https://www.zuj.edu.jo/download/introduction-to-analytic-number-theory-apostol-pdf/ and other recommended books on the PNT and $\zeta(s)$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296438/books-about-the-riemann-hypothesis or things like thisone http://www.math.illinois.edu/~ajh/ant/main5.pdf

Comment: thanks! I'll have a look at those links